# Android - There was a problem while parsing the package -- Overriding existing app with the corrected code

Tags: android, parsing, keystore, android-install-apk

I'm new to Stackoverflow. I've seen multiple solutions w.r.t above mentioned question. Please find brief details of my concern.

We deploy our Android app apk on our website. (www.mywebsiteurl.com/apk/AndroidApp.apk

And we made some changes to the code and and replaced the apk with the updated apk created using the same keystore.
We have an button enabled to prompt user to download the app whenever we find difference in version number in our servlet war file and apk verision compulsing user to update.

Update button --> This is redirecting the user to our updated Android application apk url which is on our website.

IT SAYS DOWNLOADING......

Then it says,
               There was a problem while parsing the package.

I would like to Thank you all in advance & ofcourse StackOverflow for such a beautiful platform.

Regards,
Vickey

Answer (score 0):

try Enable "Allow installation of apps from unknown sources", if it is the same I think you have signed the app with another keystore.

Comment: I checked that as well. Actually, I'm unable to undertsand the actual concern. What does this error mean. Infact on of friend showed how he used and installed updated apk through an button link. It was successfully installed (May be it was overriding the existing app).  Thank You @Mohammed Alloboany.sir for your prompt support.

Comment: if the "Allow installation of apps from unknown sources" not work, try to sign the apk with the same keystore.
Actually the debug not signed apk make these errors.